# .NET MVC interface for method

Tags: c#, .net, methods, interface

I need help with declaring method in interface. Method in implementation:

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedEnumerable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {...
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: As an **extremely simplified** rule of thumb, remove all access modifiers (`public`, `virtual` etc.) and the implementation (replace `{...}` with `;`). What's left is the interface method declaration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you would put it in an interface:

```
public interface IRepository
{
   IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedEnumerable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
}
```

or

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
   IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedEnumerable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
}
```

Comment: Second one works perfect. Thanks!!